# Gnome3+: How do I remove favorites from Dash via terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm guessing I need to edit one of the schemas available in `gsettings` but I don't know which one. and when I listed all the schemas, there's just too many of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key you want is `favorite-apps`, the schema ID is `org.gnome.shell`. Now to list your favorite apps you can simply run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

or

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

These will return an array of strings e.g.

```
['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop', 'gnome-calculator.desktop']
```

Now, to remove a value from that array you could use text processing tools like `sed`/`awk` to check if an item is in that list and remove it keeping the same format (not that trivial though definitely doable) and once you get it right just write the new settings to the database e.g. assuming you wanted to remove `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` you would run (note the double quotes):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop', 'gnome-calculator.desktop']"
```

or

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop', 'gnome-calculator.desktop']"
```

Still, it's easier to write your own utility ([using `gsettings` API](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html)) that will accept one or more desktop file names as positional parameters and remove them from favorites; to get you started, here is a very basic example in `python` that accepts one param (run as `script.py firefox.desktop`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from gi.repository import Gio,GLib
item=argv[1]
gschema = Gio.Settings('org.gnome.shell')
gvalues=gschema.get_value('favorite-apps').unpack()
if item in gvalues: gvalues.remove(item)
gschema.set_value('favorite-apps', GLib.Variant('as', gvalues))
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux Mint, these are the commands :

To query your favorites:

```
gsettings get org.x.apps.favorites list
```

To delete all your favorites:

```
gsettings reset org.x.apps.favorites list
```